# Deleting a Node in BST in a non recursive way

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Following is a piece of my code for deleting a node from a BST. It is a non-recursive code.
I have applied all the possible conditions.
However when I run my code, it stops as if stuck somewhere in an infinite loop or ending up at a point where my pointer is pointing to NULL.However I am unable to identify it.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
template <class T>
void bst<T>::delete_node(T key1)
bst_node<T>* delNode = search(key1); //delNode is the node I wish to delete

if(delNode!=root)
{
    if((delNode->left == NULL) && (delNode->right == NULL)) // node to be deleted has no children
    {
        delNode = NULL;
    }

else if((delNode->left!=NULL) && (delNode->right == NULL)) //node to be deleted has exactly one child
    {
        if(delNode->parent->left == delNode)
        {
            delNode->parent->left = delNode->left;
            delNode = NULL;
        }
        else if(delNode->parent->right == delNode)
        {
            delNode->parent->right = delNode->left;
            delNode = NULL;
        }
    }
    else if((delNode->right!= NULL) && (delNode->left == NULL))
    {
        if(delNode->parent->left == delNode)
        {
            delNode->parent->left = delNode->right;
            delNode = NULL;
        }
        else if(delNode->parent->right == delNode)
        {
            delNode->parent->right = delNode->right;
            delNode = NULL;
        }
    }
    else if((delNode->right!=NULL)&&(delNode->left != NULL)) //if has two children
    {
        bst_node<T>* temp = delNode;
        bst_node<T>* trav = delNode->right;
        if((trav->right == NULL)&&(trav->left == NULL))
        {
            delNode->value = trav->value;
            delNode->key = trav->key;
            trav = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            bst_node<T>* pred = trav;
            while(trav!=NULL)
            {
                pred = trav; //smallest node in right subtree
                trav=trav->left;
            }
            delNode->value = pred->value;
            delNode->key = pred->key;
            pred = NULL;
        }

    }
}
    else if(delNode==root)//node to be deleted is Root
    {
        if((delNode->left==NULL)&&(delNode->right==NULL))
            root = NULL;
        else if((delNode->left!=NULL) && (delNode->right == NULL)) //root has exactly one child
        {
            root = delNode->left;
            delNode = NULL;

        }
        else if((delNode->right!= NULL) && (delNode->left == NULL))
        {
            root = delNode->right;
            delNode = NULL;
        }
        else if((delNode->right!=NULL)&&(delNode->left!=NULL)) {
        bst_node<T>* temp = delNode;
        bst_node<T>* trav = delNode->right;
        if((trav->right == NULL)&&(trav->left == NULL))
        {
            delNode->value = trav->value;
            delNode->key = trav->key;
            trav = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            bst_node<T>* pred = trav;
            while(trav!=NULL)
            {
                pred = trav; //smallest node in right subtree
                trav=trav->left;
            }
            delNode->value = pred->value;
            delNode->key = pred->key;
            pred = NULL;
        }

    }
 }

}
```

Comment: Hi. @Manahil If my answer has solved your problem please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In the part:

```
else if((delNode->right!=NULL)&&(delNode->left != NULL)) //if has two children
```

when if is taken:

```
    if((trav->right == NULL)&&(trav->left == NULL))
```

the code copies the values from `trav` to `delNode` and sets `trav` to NULL:

```
delNode->value = trav->value;
delNode->key = trav->key;
trav = NULL;
```

but doesn't set `delNode->right` to `NULL`, as it should because trav didn't have any children.

the very next `else` statement which seeks for the most left node commits a similar error, because parent node's member `left` isn't set to NULL.

The next big part of the code which deals with deletion of only `root` node, seems to have identical problems, due to apparent copy-pasted (cough!) code.

Comment: but isnt delNode->right same as trav ? so if i set either to NULL it should be same thing no ?

Comment: @Manahil No those are two distinct variables. delNode->right is a pointer to a node object, as is `trav`. Apart from pointing to the same object, those two variables don't share anything. Consider: `int a = 1; int b = a; a = 0` did `b` change?

Comment: code still doesnt seem to be working :/ jus confirming if the other one is supposed to be pred->parent->left = NULL ?